# How to run code just one time in Fragment on Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my application I have some `fragments` and for show this fragments I want use `NavigationComponent`.
I have one problem. When **click** on `BottomNavigationItems` and change `fragments`, run again fragment code!
I want just run codes just **for first time**!
**My codes (for one of fragments) :**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class HomeNewFragment : Fragment(), HomeContracts.View {
    //Binding
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeNewBinding

    @Inject
    lateinit var presenter: HomePresenter

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        binding = FragmentHomeNewBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        //InitViews
        binding.apply {
            //Call apis
            presenter.callApi()
        }
    }
}
```

For example when click on items, every time call this code : `presenter.callApi()`

Or when go to **DetailFragment** and when click on back, again call `presenter.callApi()`

How can I fix it?

Comment: Use multi navi graph... Check advanced navigation in the git lab

Comment: @GobuCSG , can you send to me link for this? or source code link . thanks

Comment: I think it's a correct sample 
https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/main/NavigationAdvancedSample

Comment: Earlier I saw one util class. Now it's not there.. The class name NavigationUtil.

In that class backstack managed properly entire app

Comment: @GobuCSG thanks my friend, but I can't find any class with NavigationUtil name for managed backstack!

Comment: But you must need multi nav graph

Comment: @GobuCSG I tried your link and test multi nav example . in one of fragments I write Toast code. every time click on item again show this Toast. please see this image : https://pasteboard.co/s96CcgKQL9uY.png . this example from advance example project

Comment: When you swap fragment view will destroy. Do you aware or not instance only one....

Comment: @GobuCSG I know is destroyed. how to can it for nor destroyed and just once time?

Comment: onDestroyView only not onDestroy So you can manage it and you need below answer kind of condition if(firstTime) callApi(). Use MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace your `presenter.callApi()` with fun `onFragmentCreated` triggered in your Presenter(ViewModel).

All you need is a boolean var to check its first time or not cause your Presenter(ViewModel) attatched to the activity, not the fragment so it can store your state.

```
Presenter {
    fun onFragmentCreated() {
        if(firstTime) callApi()
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, but I used MVP architecture and I don't have viewModel! can hou help me for this and send to me code? please

Comment: Sorry I haven't ever used MVP so get no idea about the lifecycle of the Presenter

Comment: Thanks, can you send full code for MVVM?